# Slider do not add alt attribute. Cant get alt attribute from a media library!

Tags: images, gallery, slideshow, customization

I use a slider to show my post thumbnails. But the problem is that the slider adds thumbnails without the `alt` attribute:
`<img src="http://example.com/wallpaper-791556-1180x500.jpg" />`

But I want to have the `alt` attribute, as you may already guessed.
I've read a lot about it and about array, but had not succeed in fixing it. I really hope, someone would be so kind to help me.

The CODE that post images:
    `<div id="slider" class="grid-12">
    <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php   $count = of_get_option('w2f_slide_number');
    $slidecat =of_get_option('w2f_slide_categories');
    query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' =>$slidecat,'posts_per_page' =>$count ) );
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();  ?>
    <li>
    <?php
    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 1180, 500, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>
    <?php if($image) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="flex-caption">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php print_excerpt(300); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>`

And another problem is    `<div class="homegallery"> <a href="http://mysite.com/whatever/"><img class="scale" src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/slide_small.jpg"/></a>` do not show alt too! How can I fix that or where shoud I look for the code of this homegallery?

**SOLVED IT!**

Answer (score 2):

When I test `get_the_post_thumbnail` (also `the_post_thumbnail`) on WordPress 3.5.1, the `alt` attribute is added as it should be. If [you look at the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L93), you will see that [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) uses [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) which [does add that `alt` attribute](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L554). By default, that attribute is the image file name but it can be edited from `wp-admin->Media` to be anything you want.

Either:

1. A plugin or your theme has already altered the output of `get_the_post_thumbnail`, possibly via the `post_thumbnail_html` filter, though I did notice other filters in the code, or
2. Your slider or theme template doesn't work the way you think it does. Perhaps it isn't using `get_the_post_thumbnail`, for example.

It is difficult to say more, or to say exactly where this is going wrong, without seeing the relevant code.

Also, `get_the_post_thumbnail` function ***is not a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions)*** so I have to assume you are trying to hack a Core file, which you should not be doing.

Edit:

In the latest bit of code you posted, you can see the section that generates the image tag:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
```

It isn't WordPress at all, but a customized bit of code. That is where you need to add the `alt` attribute.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="I am so alt it hurts!" /></a>
```

You can create the alt attribute manually or [copy the code from `wp_get_attachment_image`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L554)

```
$default_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) )), // Use Alt field first
);
if ( empty($default_attr['alt']) )
    $default_attr['alt'] = trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )); // If not, Use the Caption                    
if ( empty($default_attr['alt']) )
    $default_attr['alt'] = trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )); // Finally, use the title
```

Or cook up your own function for creating the `alt` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, for response @s_ha_dum. I'm using slightly edited Siren theme for my site. So I pretty sure slider in it is not something unique. May be there is just a mistake in code or the author just missed that moment of adding alt attribute... What info do you need to understand my problem better?

Comment: I would need to see the code that is generating those links-- the ones without the `alt` attribute. You can start by looking in the theme's `functions.php` but some themes distribute functions over many different files.

Comment: Again... "the code that is generating those links"

Comment: @PrivatePerson : See the update

Answer (score -2):

You could try using javascript

```
jQuery('.post-thumbnail-wrapper a img').removeAttr('alt');
```

Comment: Please read the question once again. Currently there is no `alt`, and that's the problem, so I guess removing it would **not** solve it. ;)